# How much money can be transferred from India (from friend) to USA citizen | Any regulations?

Tags: money-transfer

I am a USA citizen. One of my close family friend (not a relative) can send money as a gift to me (up to 100k). Please let me know the procedure and forms that I/He have to submit with IRS/Tax departments.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing to do for you.

In the US, the gift giver has tax responsibility, and you said he is not in the US (and I assume not a US citizen).

However, the bank will report this to the IRS, and *if* they decide to investigate, you need to be able to *prove the money was not illegally acquired*. Chances are small - this amount is peanuts for them - but it could happen.